# Change always on top menu with fading php/js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I'd like to make 1 "always on top" menu on a website. I'ts different when you are actually on top,and if you scroll down the menu will change.
My problem is when the menu is changing its dissaperaing then i get the new 1.
I want the changing with fading,but i have no idea how i could do this.
(example fading always on top changing menu: http://www.aquariushand.hu/ )
Here's what i have:

HTML:

```
<div id="navi">
<div id="menu" class="default">
<img align="left" width="15%" height="100%" src="pics/a.jpeg"/>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Rólunk</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Lakóknak</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">GYIK</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Kapcsolat</a></li>

    </ul>
</div><!-- close menu -->
```

CSS:

```
#menu {
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #426d9c), color-stop(40%, #0f67a1), color-stop(100%, #1384d1));
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #426d9c, #0f67a1, #1384d1);

border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;

line-height: 20px;
text-align: center;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;
 z-index: 99;
}
.default {
width: 100%;
height: 50px;

box-shadow: 0 5px 20px #888;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 20px #888;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 20px #888;
}

.fixed {
position: fixed;
top: -5px;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 5%;

box-shadow: 0 0 40px #222;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 40px #222;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 40px #222;
}
```

JS:

```
$(function(){

var menu = $('#menu'),
    pos = menu.offset();

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(this).scrollTop() > pos.top+menu.height() && menu.hasClass('default')){
            menu.fadeOut('fast', function(){
                $(this).removeClass('default').addClass('fixed').fadeIn('fast');
            });
        } else if($(this).scrollTop() <= pos.top && menu.hasClass('fixed')){
            menu.fadeOut('fast', function(){
                $(this).removeClass('fixed').addClass('default').fadeIn('fast');
            });
        }
    });

});
```

I want something like like on the example page.

Answer (score 0):

On your CSS you should add `position` and give it `fixed` value like

```css
#menu {
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #426d9c), color-stop(40%, #0f67a1), color-stop(100%, #1384d1));
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #426d9c, #0f67a1, #1384d1);

border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;

line-height: 20px;
text-align: center;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;
  position:fixed;
 z-index: 99;
}
.default {
width: 100%;
height: 50px;

box-shadow: 0 5px 20px #888;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 20px #888;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 20px #888;
}
```

Anyway I don't see where you are using `.fixed` class

Comment: im using the .fixed class in the JS, its changing the menu class based on the scroll position. The fading should go to the css also,right?